# Tab functionality to navigate inside the input positions in masked text box control

Tags: c#, wpf, maskedtextbox

I have a masked text box custom control which accepts text in the format
" _ _ w _ _ d _ _ h _ _ m". My requirement is to have the tab functionality working inside the control. Say if my cursor is in the first input position ( first underscore before the w letter ( _ _ w )). Then on pressing tab, it should go to the next input position. Please guide.

Thanks,

Divya

Comment: What language? What platform?

Comment: Sorry to add that information. WPF application in .Net 4.0 using C#

Comment: @user3323130 did you figure this out?